# Replace characters in specific columns only (CSV)

Tags: linux, csv, awk, sed

I have data like this:

```
1;2015-04-10;23:10:00;10.4.2015 23:10;8.9;1007.5;0.3;0.0;0;55
2;2015-04-10;23:20:00;10.4.2015 23:20;8.6;1007.8;0.4;0.0;0;56
3;2015-04-10;23:30:00;10.4.2015 23:30;8.5;1008.1;0.4;0.0;0;57
```

It has dot `.` as decimal separator but I need to use `,` instead.

Desired data:

```
1;2015-04-10;23:10:00;10.4.2015 23:10;8,9;1007,5;0,3;0,0;0;55
```

I tried using `Sed`. With `sed -i 's/\./,/g' myfile.csv` I could replace all dots with commas but would destroy dates on the fourth column. How can I change dots to commas in elsewhere but leave the fourth column as it is? If some other `Linux` tool is better for this task than `Sed` I could use it as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions, for anything else just use awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) sub(/\./,",",$i)} 1' file
1;2015-04-10;23:10:00;10.4.2015 23:10;8,9;1007,5;0,3;0,0;0;55
2;2015-04-10;23:20:00;10.4.2015 23:20;8,6;1007,8;0,4;0,0;0;56
3;2015-04-10;23:30:00;10.4.2015 23:30;8,5;1008,1;0,4;0,0;0;57
```

Comment: This works. Could you give short explanation on how exactly this works? I'd like to understand how it works and the syntax looks quite complex.

Comment: Sure - `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}` = set the field-separator to a `;`. `{for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) sub(/\./,",",$i)}` = starting at the 5th field, replace every `.` with `,` in each field. `1` = invoke the defaulkt action of printing the current line. Awk has less than 10 fundamental (important but very simple) things to understand and then the rest is just a stripped down, simplified C-like syntax focused on manipulating text. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks, it looks more clear now. I think I will find it useful to study this tool more.

Comment: You NEED to know awk if you use UNIX. The alternative is to create horrible, messy, slow, fragile hacks using combinations of shell, sed, grep, etc. The guys who invented UNIX shell invented awk to manipulate text in a UNIX environment - just do it they way they intended and save yourself a lot of pain. Unlike every other general purpose text processing tool, awk comes as standard with every UNIX installation just like sed and grep.

Answer (score 0):

Perl and [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({ binary      => 1,
                             sep_char    => ';',
                             quote_space => 0,
                           }) or die 'Text::CSV'->error_diag;
open my $FH, '<:encoding(utf8)', 'input.csv' or die $!;
$csv->eol("\n");
while (my $row = $csv->getline($FH)) {
    s/\./,/g for @$row[ 0 .. 2, 4 .. $#$row ];
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {if(NF==5);gsub(/\./,",",$5)} 1 ' filename
```

Here I have used `gsub` instead of `sub`; the difference is that `sub` will replace only the first occurrence, whereas `gsub` will replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

changes dot to comma in second column

```
awk '{gsub(/\./,",",$2)}1' file

1;2015-04-10;23:10:00;10.4.2015 23:10;8,9;1007,5;0,3;0,0;0;55
2;2015-04-10;23:20:00;10.4.2015 23:20;8,6;1007,8;0,4;0,0;0;56
3;2015-04-10;23:30:00;10.4.2015 23:30;8,5;1008,1;0,4;0,0;0;57
```